# Verify my phone number in my app

Tags: java, android, sms

I am trying to verify the phone number of a device by having the device send a SMS to itself, but I want the message to appear like if the app was the one who send it and not my device.

Here is my project, but when I verify the number. In my inbox it appears that I send and received the message. Is it possible to do that? If it is, how can I change that?

[image]

Comment: Please paste your code in the question, don't use screenshots of your code to show us your problem.

Comment: I would assume it is the cellular provider that actually controls the number attached to received SMS. If the sender (your application) had control over that then it would be possible for anyone to send a text message as someone else which sounds like a bad idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Android added protections a few versions ago that prevent you from sending hidden text messages. Someone may have a better workaround, but as far as I know it is impossible to hide the text from the user. IMO it is not that big of a deal if the user sees the text you send as long as the verification works.